# How can I get the value of the checkbox to be saved in the firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, material-ui

I have this checkbox where the user can check all of the checkbox. I cannot save this in the firestore as it has an error every time I submit it and says:

```
 TypeError: s.indexOf is not a function
```

and if I check all of checkbox and i'll `console.log(state);` it shows this:

```
item1: true
item2: true
item3: true
```

what I wanted was just when the specific checkbox (item1 and item2) was clicked, it will just output something like this:

```
item1 
item2
```

Below are the entire codes:

```
const component = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    Fever: false,
    Headache: false,
    Nausea: false,
    "Muscle Pain": false,
  });
  const handleCheckbox = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setState({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    for (const p in state) {
      if (!state[p]) delete state[p];
    }
    try {
      const userRef = firestore.collection("users").doc(uid);
      const ref = userRef.set({
        state,
      });
      console.log(" saved");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <FormGroup style={{ alignContent: "center", padding: "1rem" }}>
            <FormControlLabel
              control={
                <Checkbox
                  checked={state.Fever}
                  name="Item1"
                  color="primary"
                  value="Item1"
                  onChange={handleCheckbox}
                />
              }
              label="Item1"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              control={
                <Checkbox
                  checked={state.Headache}
                  name="Item2"
                  color="primary"
                  value="Item2"
                  onChange={handleCheckbox}
                />
              }
              label="Item2"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              control={
                <Checkbox
                  checked={state.Nausea}
                  name="Item3"
                  color="primary"
                  value="Item3"
                  onChange={handleCheckbox}
                />
              }
              label="Item3"
            />
         
          </FormGroup>
          <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
        <br />
      </form>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default component;
```

How can I get the values of item1, item2, and item3 so I can save it as it is in the firestore? Thank you.

Comment: From your `state` you just want to fetch all the items that has value are `true` right?

Comment: @NeelDsouza yes and I wanted to store the data in firestore with their corresponding values like `item1` and `item2` and etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newState = {...state};
    for (const p in newState) {
      if (!newState[p]) delete newState[p];
    }
    try {
      const userRef = firestore.collection("users").doc(uid);
      const ref = userRef.set({
        newState,
      });
      console.log(" saved");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

  };
```

Comment: Also in future never mutate your state directly bcz you are just making change to its reference. Also make a copy of it and then change